# Bind a modifier key (like right shift) to a command?

Tags: key-bindings

I often use the `M-x` command. Is it possible to bind it to my right shift (just the right shift, because I like my left shift the way it is)?

---

Alright, big thanks to the chosen answer. I solved the problem this way:

```
# Issued whenever the keyboard layout is changed.
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = F13"
```

Then, in my Emacs config, I bind `#'smex` to `<f13>`.  If you use the standard `#'execute-extended-command`, use the first (commented) line.

```
;; (global-set-key (kbd "<f13>") (function execute-extended-command))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f13>") (function smex))
```

Comment: No, it is not possible, at least purely within Emacs.  The modifier keys (like shift) have to modify something before Emacs actually sees the keys.  As an alternative, you can change the shift key to something else at the OS level (`xmodmap` for Linux, `karabiner` for OSX, etc.) and then map *that* key.

Comment: I generalized the title a bit as this seems like a potentially common question. Feel free to change if you disagree.

Comment: @Dan: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible, at least purely within Emacs.

The [modifier keys](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModifierKeys) (like <kbd>shift</kbd>) have to modify something before Emacs actually sees the keys. As an alternative, you can change the shift key to something else at the OS level ([`xmodmap`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap) for Linux, [`karabiner`](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) for OSX, etc.) and then map *that* key to the desired command.

For example: at the OS level, you could map your key to something that Emacs knows about but does not actually exist on your keyboard (say, <kbd>f20</kbd>), and then bind <kbd>f20</kbd> to your command within Emacs.  The downside, of course, is that *every* program you use, not just Emacs, sees your key as <kbd>f20</kbd>.

Comment: It should be noted that Emacs can see the modifier key. E.g. [here's a way for Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813630/detecting-the-right-shift-key-in-qt) library, i.e. it's possible in general. The problem rather that elisp doesn't provide any way to bind anything to it. Someone has to report a feature request on that.

Answer (score 2):

My Windows-**Menu** key runs `execute-extended-command` (as `M-x` does).

It's very close to the Shift key.
It can be changed too...

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<menu>") 'find-file)
```