# How to have Emacs treat left Ctrl as Hyper?

Tags: key-bindings

I never use the left control key, so I'd like to rebind it as Hyper, but ONLY inside Emacs. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I'm running Emacs on a linux system.

Comment: Interesting, you don't use C-n and C-p for motion?

Comment: @eflanigan00 - I do, but I have C mapped to Caps Lock.

Comment: I've never done it but is xmodmap the way to go? http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21892/bind-a-modifier-key-like-right-shift-to-a-command

Comment: @eflanigan00 - thanks, but I can't use that as it modifies the key system wide rather than just in Emacs. xmodmap also doesn't work on Wayland.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be able to change what the control modifier is mapped to [in the upcoming major Emacs release](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24822).  While this isn't as fine-grained as it could be to remap only one of both control modifiers, it allows remapping them to hyper in Emacs only:

```
(setq x-ctrl-keysym 'hyper)
```

Feel free to open a bug report for individual modifier remappings.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac you can try adding the following to your init.el

```
(setq mac-control-modifier 'hyper)
```

I believe `(setq ns-control-modifier 'hyper)` would be the general solution for other OSes, I wouldn't know it, though.

To change the right control key you'd similarly use `(setq mac-right-control-modifier 'hyper)`. To control the behaviour of other "meta" keys change `control` for either `option`, `command` or `function`, e.g., `mac-command-modifier`.

Comment: `ns` is the prefix used by the official Emacs for macOS. `mac` is used by another macOS Emacs port. However, in this case, the official macOS Emacs also understands the `mac` prefix, probably because the feature originated on the other Emacs port.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not on a mac (linux, I'll edit the original question). I don't seem to have any variables called anything like `control-modifier`.

Comment: @Lindydancer The ns prefix is from NeXT and dates back to early 1990s OSX was based on NeXTStep so I think you have it the wrong way round

Comment: @Mark, you're absolutely correct in that "ns" stands for NextSTEP. The "ns" prefix is still used to refer to the official macOS port of Emacs, as it's based on the Emacs port for NextSTEP. All macOS-specific variables and functions are prefixed with ns-, e.g. `ns-popup-font-panel` and `ns-auto-hide-menu-bar`.